# Sans-serif bold math with newtxmath

Tags: math-mode, fonts, bold, sans-serif, newtxmath

I'm writing an article whose math font needs to be Times New Roman. To this end, I'm using the `newtxmath` package. However, it doesn't seem to support sans-serif bold in math mode.

Usually I can write

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

Sans serif, no bold: $\mathsf{A}, \mathsf{\Omega}$

Sans serif, bold: $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}}, \boldsymbol{\mathsf{\Omega}}$

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: Correct output, no newtxmath]

However, when the `newtxmath` is included

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Sans serif, no bold: $\mathsf{A}, \mathsf{\Omega}$

Sans serif, bold: $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}}, \boldsymbol{\mathsf{\Omega}}$

\end{document}
```

one gets

[image: Wrong output with newtxmath]

Is there any workaround to this? Using `mathptmx` instead isn't the best option, since I also need upright Greek symbols which are provided automatically in `newtxmath`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should also load `newtxtext`, for the text fonts. A small correction should be made as well, for `\mathsf{\Omega}`. Also load `bm`, which is better than the standard version for `\boldsymbol` provided by `amsmath`. You can also use `\bm` instead of `\boldsymbol`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}


\begin{document}

Sans serif, no bold: $\mathsf{A}, \mathsf{\Omega}$

Sans serif, bold: $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}}, \boldsymbol{\mathsf{\Omega}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was using `times` for the text font as `newtxtext` wouldn't even render `\mathsf{\Omega}` at all, but now it's working perfectly with your correction. Thank you.

Comment: i like this but it will only work with upper case greek letters. How can I make it work with lower case?

Comment: @JPeterson You need a whole new symbol font with sans serif Greek lowercase, with a boldface variant.