# Newtxmath font shape warnings with siunitx and bm

Tags: siunitx, newtxmath, boldmath

I want to use newtxtext and newtxmath fonts in combination with siunitx. I also need bold math so I added the bm package as described in:
[Sans-serif bold math with newtxmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303568/sans-serif-bold-math-with-newtxmath)

Now I am facing font shape line warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/ntxtlf/sb/n' undefined
```

Does anyone know a solution? Especially which characters are subsituted?

Thank you!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[libertine, vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm} %Bold math
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}     
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you loading the option libertine if your text font is newtxtext?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to get to you so late.  Just saw this question in a search for duplicates of another.

This problem is unrelated to `siunitx` and (on TeX Live 2019) still appears if you omit the package.  As Ulrike Fischer hinted, the problem is that you loaded `newtxtext` together with the `libertine` option of `newtxmath`.  For bold upright letters (such as capital Greek letters), this causes the package to look for a semibold weight of the Times-based text font, which does not exist (`newtxlf/sb/n` is New Times with lining figures, semibold weight, upright shape).

To fix this, load the `libertine` package as your text font instead.  You should give it the `semibold` option to match the bold math.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book} 
\usepackage[lining, semibold, type1]{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[libertine, vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm} %Bold math
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}     
Test
\end{document}
```

I loaded `libertine` with the `type1` option to prevent the package from loading `fontspec` on LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  Although there are other workarounds, this is mainly so that upright capital Greek letters such as `\Delta` will still work.  Legacy packages such as `newtxmath` look for them in the 7-bit OT1 encoding.

In the modern toolchain, with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, you can instead load `libertinus` to use the Libertinus Math font, or `unicode-math` followed by `\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}`.