# Bold math with \usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

Tags: bold, libertine, newtxmath

I am not sure why when I try to use \usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath} and have an equation with boldsymbol, this message appears:

Font shape `OT1/txr/sb/n' undefined(Font) using`OT1/txr/m/n' instead

Is there something wrong with this? What can I do to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: [A very similar question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303568/sans-serif-bold-math-with-newtxmath)

Comment: [Even closer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402353/newtxmath-font-shape-warnings-with-siunitx-and-bm/507855#507855)

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newtx/doc/newtxdoc.pdf) load `bm` after all math packages to get bold math, and use `\bm`.  The package also supports `\mathbf` for bold upright text in math mode.  This appears to be caused by the way `bm` sets up `\mathbf`.

Here is a slight modification of an example from the manual:

```
\usepackage[lining,semibold,type1]{libertine} % a bit lighter than Times--no osf in math
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % best for Western European languages
\usepackage{textcomp} % required to get special symbols
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}% a typewriter font must be defined
\usepackage[libertine,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=rsfso]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{bm}% load after all math to give access to bold math
```

I added the `type1` option to `libertine` to prevent the package from loading the Unicode font through `fontspec` on LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  You could load it after `bm` to use the `fontspec` definition of `\mathbf`, but then upright capital Greek letters would break, because `newtx` looks for those in the seven-bit OT1 encoding.  There are other workarounds, but this is the simplest.

In the modern toolchain, you can instead load `\usepackage{libertinus}` to get the Libertinus Math font, or `unicode-math` followed by `\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}`.  This enables the legacy `\mathbf` (for bolded words), and the new commands `\symbfup` and `\symbfit` for letters and numbers.  You can still use `\boldsymbol`,`\boldmath` and `\mathversion{bold}` to get symbols from Libertinus Math Bold.  (You can thank Khaled Hosny for being one of the only font designers who makes bold OpenType math fonts.)